# INSERT change number of values in PHP to mySql

Tags: php, sql

in PHP, how can i `INSERT` change number of values to mySql?!

> example:
>
> in one time i can `INSERT` 6 values. after that it can be 12 values.
>   and after that 2 values.

**edit:**
sql example:

```
//first time it can be:

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table 
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h') VALUES
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h') ") 
or die(mysql_error());

// after that it can be:

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table 
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') VALUES
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: give us example with sql queries - one time which query and second time which query?

Comment: Post an example query.

Comment: What is the issue, based on the values use the loop construct the values dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want dynamic insert queries?

```
function createQuery($data)
{
    $sqlTemplate = "INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s)";

    $columns = implode(',', array_keys($data));
    $values = implode(',', $data);
    $sql = sprintf($sqlTemplate, $columns, $values);

    return $sql;
}

createQuery(array(
    'a' => 'val1',
    'b' => 'val2'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of sql injection.I haven't managed it in the query.But i think this is what you need.You have to manage the sql vulnerabilities if you are using this

```
$arr = array('name'=>'Test','age'=>'25','sex'=>'Male','status'=>'1');
$strInsrt = 'INSERT INTO table ';
$a_Colums = '';
$a_Values = '';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $a_Colums .= $key.',';
    $a_Values .= "'".$value."',";
}

$strInsrt .= "(".rtrim($a_Colums,',').") VALUES (".rtrim($a_Values,',').")";
echo $strInsrt;
```